# Where is my database? MySQL data successfully send to Database not found on server

Tags: mysql

Here is as follows:

a) Run mysqld
b) In the Windows 7 Command Prompt type:

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -p
```

MySQL asks me for my:

password:

After a valid password is provided MYSQL it lets me in.

All I see is the information_scheme and test databases.

I SHOULD see what I created for my servlet of which is connecting to 'some database without mine'.

Prior to this (i didnt know anything of the above) my servlet is programed to insert data into my users table tables. Similarly with outher tables. Keep in mind that this a SERVLET that sends its data to a 'users' database with user and other tables.

My Question is: Why is MySQL now showing databases? Yet its allowing me to insert from a Servlet?

Oddly enough it works...

Where is my database?

Comment: have you tried running a query to show it? aka using `SHOW` ??

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR youruser@localhost`.  MySQL will explicitly _not_ show databases your currently logged-in user@host does not have grants for.  Is the Servlet application connecting with the same user you just used on the command line?

Comment: If you log in with a more privileged user, you should see it:  `mysql -uroot -p`

Comment: Thanks Mike!!!! Post as answer and I will accept.